# I lost my BTC from 3 USA BTC traders

Tags: fraud, hitbtc

I lost money nearing 10k.USD from 3 BTC traders. How to recovers. please help me. 
What is the procedure for complaint against BTC Traders. 
Still one person is asking for 150$ for Transfer Fee, Another one also. 
I am ready to share full details( name / phone.no / mail-id address etc).
if any one reply me.

Answer (score 4):

> **What is the procedure for complaint against BTC Traders.**

Contact your local police if you believe someone has fraudulently taken your money.

I don't know who you mean by BTC Traders but that is probably not important.

If you mean btctraders.cc, their [website FAQ](https://btctraders.cc/?a=faq) says "BTC TRADERS Limited is a private limited company registered in UK under Company No. 10561882". But that is the number of a [different company that has been dissolved](https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/search?q=10561882). This means btctraders.cc is not the sort of company I would give my money to.

If you mean three different people who just claimed to be traders in the Bitcoin currency, then I guess you've been tricked by several criminals.

> **one person is asking for 150$ for Transfer Fee**

That is typical of scammers/fraudsters/tricksters.

> **I am ready to share full details( name / phone.no / mail-id address etc)**

You will be contacted by people either offering to recover your money or telling you about marvellous people who can recover all your money. These are liars trying to trick you out of more money by inventing more fees - transfer fees, release fees, investigation fees and anything else they can think of.

Ignore them.